# How do I dump blessed hash ref?

Tags: perl

```
  DB<126> x $dbh
0  DBI::db=HASH(0x11e0bd0)
     empty hash
```

It seems I can't dump its content no matter how many stuff I assign to it by `$dbh->{$a} = $v`

why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DBI handles are an example of inside out objects; they squirrel away their attributes where you in theory can't get them except through their interface.  (Unlike many newer implementations of inside out objects, they also have a tie interface that allows you to get and set attributes as if they were blessed hashes, but in a controlled way.)

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to debug DBI consider using DBI's powerful [tracing](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#TRACING) method which works for the database driver as well as DBI itself.